# Unsupported operation exception from spark: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType is not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

**Spark Streaming:**

I am receiving a dataframe that consists of two columns. The first column is of `string` type that contains a `json` string and the second column consists of `schema` for each `value`(first column).

```
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+--------------------+
|               value|              schema|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|{"event_time_abc...|`event_time_abc...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

The table is stored in the `val input`(non mutable variable). I am using `DataType.fromDDL` function to convert the `string` type to a `json` DataFrame in the following way:

```
val out=  input.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),ddl(col("schema"))))
```

where `ddl` is a predefined function,`DataType.from_ddl(_:String):DataType` in spark(scala) but i have registered it so that i can use it on whole column instead of a string only. I have done it in following way:

```
val ddl:UserDefinedFunction = udf(DataType.fromDDL(_:String):DataType)
```

and here is the final transformation on both column, value and schema of `input` table.

```
val out =  input.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),ddl(col("schema"))))
```

However, i get exception from the registration at this line:

`val ddl:UserDefinedFunction = udf(DataType.fromDDL(_:String):DataType)`

The error is:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType is not supported
```

If i use:

```
val out =  input.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"),DataType.fromDDL("`" + "event_time_human2"+"`" +" STRING")).alias("value"))
```

then it works but as you see i am only using a `string`(manually typed coming from the `schema` column) inside the function `DataType.fromDDL(_:String):DataType`.

So how can i apply this function to whole column without registration or is there any other way to register the function?

EDIT: `from_json` function's first argument requires a column while second argument requires a `schema` and not a column. Hence, i guess a manual approach is required to parse each `value` field with each `schema` field. After some investigation i found out that DataFrames do not support DataType.

---

Since a bounty has been set on this question. I would like to provide additional information regarding the data and schema. The schema is defined in DDL(string type) and it can be parsed with `from_DDL` function. The value is simple `json` string that will be parsed with the schema that we derive using `from_DDL` function.

The basic idea is that each value has it's own schema and needs to be parsed with corresponding schema. A new column should be created where the result will be store.

Data:
Here is one example of the data:

value = `{"event_time_human2":"09:45:00 +0200 09/27/2021"}`

schema = "`event_time_human2` STRING"

It is not needed to convert to correct time format. Just a string will be fine.

It is in `streaming context`. So ,not all  approaches work.

Comment: `col("schema")` is literally just a named Column object, not the selected string content of that one cell

Comment: @OneCricketeer ddl is registered by me and it takes a string but after registration spark passes it a column and not string.

Comment: "Take a string", okay, but you are giving it a column object which type is undefined. What is the schema of `input`?

Comment: Maybe try defining a UDF that accepts two parameters that takes both columns and runs `from_json` on that?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i tried that when i pass both columns then the output of from_json function is a column which is again undefined. So i can't pass back the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schemas are being applied and validated before runtime, that is, before the Spark code is executed on the executors. Parsed schemas must be part of the execution plan therefore schema parsing can't be executed dynamically as you intended until now. This is the reason that you see the exception:
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType is not supported`  only for the UDF. Consequently that implies that `DataType.fromDDL` should be used only inside the driver code and not in the runtime/executor code, which is the code within your UDF function. Inside the UDF function Spark has already executed the transformation of the imported data applying the schemas that you specified on the driver side. This is the reason that you can't use `DataType.fromDDL` directly in your UDF because it is essentially useless. All the above means that inside the UDF functions we can only use primitive Scala/Java types and some wrappers provided by the Spark API i.e WrappedArray.

An alternative could be to collect all the schemas on the driver. Then create a map with the pair (schema, dataframe) for each schema.

*Keep in mind that collecting data to the driver is an expensive operation and it would make sense only if you have a reasonable number of unique schemas, i.e max some thousands. Also, applying these schemas to each dataset need to be done sequentially in the driver, which is quite expensive too, therefore it is important to realize that the suggested solution will only work efficiently if you have a limited amount of unique schemas.*

Up to this point, your code could look as next:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("""{"event_time_human2":"09:45:00 +0200 09/27/2021", "name":"Pinelopi"}""", "`event_time_human2` STRING, name STRING"),
  ("""{"first_name":"Pin", "last_name":"Halen"}""", "first_name STRING, last_name STRING"),
  ("""{"code":993, "full_name":"Sofia Loren"}""", "code INT, full_name STRING")
).toDF("value", "schema")

val schemaDf = df.select("schema").distinct()

val dfBySchema = schemaDf.collect().map{ row =>
  val schemaValue = row.getString(0)
  val ddl = StructType.fromDDL(schemaValue)
  val filteredDf = df.where($"schema" === schemaValue)
                     .withColumn("value", from_json($"value", ddl))
  
  (schemaValue, filteredDf)
}.toMap

// Map(
//   `event_time_human2` STRING, name STRING -> [value: struct<event_time_human2: string, name: string>, schema: string], 
//   first_name STRING, last_name STRING -> [value: struct<first_name: string, last_name: string>, schema: string], 
//   code INT, full_name STRING -> [value: struct<code: int, full_name: string>, schema: string]
// )
```

**Explanation**: first we gather each unique schema with `schemaDf.collect()`. Then we iterate through schemas and filter the initial df based on the current schema. We also use `from_json` to convert current string value column to the specific schema.

*Note* that we can't have one common column with different data type, this is the reason that we are creating a different df for each schema and not one final df.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. I will check in streaming context if it works then i will accept your answer. As far as i know each time a new micro batch comes in(streams) then we collect again distinct schemas. Is it possible to just collect all distinct schemas once(from first batch) and keep them in memory. Each subsequent batch will be tested with already existing schemas and if there is an exception then we can extract it's corresponding schema and parse it?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that your code does not work in streaming mode.  I get following error ``Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()`

Comment: for streaming you will have to restart your program in order to collect all your schemas on the driver and then reload all the collected schemas. I am not aware of any alternative here unfortunately. Also, please update your question with this specific information because it is an important detail

Comment: It is not important but if any solution works for streams then it will be fine.

Comment: @KhanSaab for streaming you will need to follow a completely different approach. As a matter of fact, you should not use Spark DDL schema representation at all. One solution would be to store the schema in a different format i.e Avro, and then parse the validate the json value in a UDF function. Again, this constitutes a completely different problem than the one described in the above question. I believe it is a better idea to write a new question in which you should explain what precisely you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have written clearly that it is in streaming context. Each mico batch consists of string and a schema for that string.  The word STREAMING CONTEXT is mentioned on top. The original data coming from kafka has a string and ddl schema. I have no access to change the data and re-ingest into kafka and then later read with streams.

Comment: However, If avro works for streaming context then i can definitely transform ddl schema to avro but still we will face same problem(in streaming context).

Comment: sorry I missed the title of the post completely. Can you please provide an example how you would like to use this data? For example you want to extract a particular field in the schema?

Comment: @albiratsis no problem. The data is coming as shown in table(with heading mico batch). One column shows the input string and second column shows the ddl(in string format). We want to use the ddl to parse the string(json) from first column to build a dataframe.

Comment: from what I know you are not able to build a dataframe on the fly as you initially thought. The reason is described in the above answer, that is the schema must be known already in the driver in order to build a dataframe. In your case you have to collect somehow the available schemas and the restart the stream. That of course is not what you need. This is the reason I am asking for the final query, what exactly you want to do with the final dataframes? Can you give an example of how do you plan to use the final output?

Comment: Just to do some transformation on some fields and then store it in .parquet format on HDFS.